# What is a 'bistro car' (or what should it be called instead)?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

According to [Wikipedia page on dining car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_car), dining car is the same to restaurant carriage and diner.

While in the last paragraph it says

> The U76/U70 tram line between the German cities of Düsseldorf and
>    Krefeld offers a **Bistrowagen** (dining car in German), where passengers
>    can order **drinks** and snacks.

It sounds like Bistro car is sort of a German-origin term for dining car. But referring to Google images,  the top results look like drinking bars more than dining rooms.

So I'm wondering what Bistro car means (if it exists) and is it suitable to name a dining car (that doesn't serve alcohols) as a 'Bistro car'?

Comment: The term ***Bistro car*** simply means the speaker is using a (possibly second- or third-hand) translation. It doesn't have any special meaning in English as such, beyond the obvious implication that bistros are more about drinks and snacks than ***dining cars*** (where the emphasis is more on having a substantial meal). So perhaps some people might deliberately use ***bistro car*** to distinguish it from a dining car (or indeed from a ***buffet car*** where you're less likely to be able to buy alcohol),

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about German usage, not English

Comment: @FumbleFingers But where should I post this question to? I don't study German and English is a germanic language.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Given you don't study German, and Anglophones don't use this particular German expression, why do you want to ask about (discuss?) the usage at all? If you simply mean *Is it appropriate to sprinkle unfamiliar foreign expressions into an English discourse?*, I think the answer is that would be Off Topic (all a matter of opinion) here. Maybe there's an SO "Etiquette" site, I dunno.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I came up with this question because the China High-speed Railways named the dining cars in their trains as 'Bistro car'. Where they don't serve drinks at all. Also I failed to get any suffcient evidence on the internet that the term is "adequate" in any usage. I don't mean to sprinkle unfamiliar foreign expressions into an English discourse.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What I meant by mensioning 'English is a germanic language' is that a lot of the words in the English language was originated, or as you said, 'sprinkled' into English from other languages(especially Germanic languages), even the language of Anglo-Saxons were technically a germanic language. Which means if I am putting this question to no-one-knows-which-but-etiquette or the German language .se site, applying the same rule, most of the questions about etymological usage /terms whatnot on this site will need to be sorted out as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27602/discussion-between-aaron-drake-and-fumblefingers).

Comment: I don't think this should be closed simply because the material that prompted the question talked about German. The way I read the question, it's asking if something exists/is acceptable in English, which is certainly on-topic here.

Comment: @ColleenV: I don't understand your logic. What we have here is a German word that happens to be defined (*as* a German word) in a Wikipedia article on dining cars. There's no reason to suppose it even *exists* as an English word, and even less reason to suppose that if it *did*, it would mean anything different to what it does in German. I really don't see why ELL should be addressing such issues.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Because while it's obvious to you and me, someone learning English, which does have lots of borrowed words from other languages, doesn't know. Bistro is a word we use in English, and I think there is something to be said about it to help explain why it might not make sense applied to a dining car.

Comment: @ColleenV: Sure, the word ***bistro*** has been adopted into English. That means it's easy to look it up in any dictionary. Would we entertain a question asking what a "bistro chair" or a "bistro table" meant?

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question isn't about the meaning, it's about whether it's suitable/usable for naming a railroad car. I think if someone asked "Can I call this 8 foot long wood table with attached benches a bistro table?" that would be on-topic too. I just decided to do a search and it looks like Amtrak does use "bistro car" http://www.amtrakcascades.com/OnBoard.htm. Going to have to edit my answer  now :/

Answer (score 3):

The English definition of [bistro](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/bistro) includes the idea of wine or other alcoholic beverages being served. I think of a bistro as a "European style" small restaurant with wine available to eat with your meal and some sort of outdoor seating, usually in the area in front of the bistro.

It turns out that at least one rail line, Amtrak Cascades, does [refer to their dining car as a "Bistro Car"](http://www.amtrakcascades.com/OnBoard.htm). It does serve alcoholic beverages as well as soups, sandwiches, and snacks. I think that they used bistro instead of dining car to make it seem [classy](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/classy).

Also consider that a [diner](https://www.wordnik.com/words/diner) in the US has evolved to mean a "A small, usually inexpensive restaurant with a long counter and booths and housed in a building designed to resemble a dining car." where it used to mean just the dining car of a train.

[image: Image of a diner]

And as Karen pointed out, the primary feature of diners is a usually inexpensive, simple menu with seating that includes a counter, and not necessarily the shape of the building.

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest that diner has evolved away from the long, narrow building definition to any restaurant that has a diner style counter and a basic, American-food menu, usually inexpensive.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bistro):

> A bistro is, in its original Parisian incarnation, a small restaurant, serving moderately priced simple meals in a modest setting.

So, yes, it is appropriate to name a dining car a Bistrowagen (in German) and bistro car in English.

Comment: Not in the context on *English!* Apart from anything else, we spell the second part ***wagon*** (***wagen*** is out-and-out German). The word ***bistro*** has been pretty well integrated into English, but we call the section of a train a ***car*** or ***carriage*** anyway, so it seems to me this German expression is highly unlikely to gain currency with Anglophones.

Comment: To be pedantic, the origin of Bistro is Russian.  It is the russian for 'quickly' and was adopted by the French during the Napoleonic wars to refer to fast food.